# IF, ELIF, ELSE statement indentation

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a program based on the library SinricPro. It controls a servo through alexa. I've got the bit working that connects the RPi to Alexa, and the servo controlled from the RPi GPIO, but I need to get the bit working where Alexa controls the Servo.

I'm trying to use an IF statement, but I always get an indentation error. I've tried multiple ways of indenting, but none work... Anyone got any ideas about how to get it working with the correct indentation?

The IF statement that is being complained about:

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1eUB.png)

The error:

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9LRR.png)

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: Please put a [mre] in the question

Answer (score 1):

If you put actual indented code after `if`, `elif` or `else`, the error should disappear.

Alternatively, you can add `pass` or `...`, if you want the code to run without doing anything. This is also true for functions, thus a dummy function could look like

```py
def dummy():
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to fill out the statement, you need to add `pass` under each block.

Comment: You can interestingly enough also use ellipses `...` instead of `pass`